# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.batik.css.engine.SVGCSSEngine

Tags: java, svg, primefaces, png

I have my implementation of the conversion and generates the PNG works perfectly in my jboss 7.1.1, but when I try it on a Linux machine java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError I get the error: Could not initialize class org.apache.batik.css.engine .SVGCSSEngine. They have any idea why?
I appreciate your collaboration.

My Pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

My Javascript, call from remoteCommand of primefaces my Bean

```
function objToString() {
var a = document.getElementById("dientesvg");
var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
var cadena = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgDoc);
document.getElementById("form1:cadenaOdontograma").value = cadena;
obtenerDibujo();}
```

My Java

```
public void obtenerDibujo() throws TranscoderException, IOException,
        AppBaseException {
    imagenOdontograma = new ByteArrayInputStream(
            cadenaOdontograma.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    TranscoderInput inputSvgImage = new TranscoderInput(imagenOdontograma);
    Parametro param = parametroFacade
            .consultarParametroPorClave("URL_ARCHIVOS_TEMP");
    carpetaArchivos = param.getValor();
    OutputStream pngOstream = new FileOutputStream(carpetaArchivos + "_"
            + historiaGeneral.getConsecutivo() + ".png");
    TranscoderOutput outputPngImage = new TranscoderOutput(pngOstream);

    PNGTranscoder myConverter = new PNGTranscoder();
    myConverter.transcode(inputSvgImage, outputPngImage);
    pngOstream.flush();
    pngOstream.close();

    imagen = ImageIO.read(new File(carpetaArchivos + "_"
            + historiaGeneral.getConsecutivo() + ".png"));

}
```

Comment: You mention primefaces; are you deploying this as a war, an ear or an exploded directory? Is there anything in the logs? When you set JBoss to debug mode?

Comment: The cause can most likely be found in the FULL stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel, a NoClassDefFoundError is raised when at compile time the dependency was satisfied BUT at run time the Classloader was not able to find that class, i would encourage you to check if in the deployment file/directory or environment is present or available the corresponding dependency that holds the org.apache.batik.css.engine.SVGCSSEngine class.

Comment: I added other maven dependencies of Batik and it worked properly.